# How to setup nginx with opencart 1.5.5?

Tags: php, nginx, opencart

It is possible to use nginx with OpenCart? I am using following nginx zone:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /home/username/Development/shop.local;
        index index.php;

        server_name shop.local;

        location /image/data {
                autoindex on;
        }

        location /admin {
                index index.php;
        }

        location / {
                try_files $uri @opencart;
        }

        location @opencart {
                rewrite ^/(.+)$ /index.php?_route_=$1 last;
        }

        location = /favicon.ico {
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
        }

        location = /robots.txt {
                allow all;
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
        }


        # Make sure files with the following extensions do not get loaded by nginx because nginx would display the source code, and these files can contain PASSWORDS!
        location ~* \.(engine|inc|info|install|make|module|profile|test|po|sh|.*sql|theme|tpl(\.php)?|xtmpl)$|^(\..*|Entries.*|Repository|Root|Tag|Template)$|\.php_ {
                deny all;
        }

        # Deny all attempts to access hidden files such as .htaccess, .htpasswd, .DS_Store (Mac).
        location ~ /\. {
                deny all;
                access_log off;
                log_not_found off;
        }

        location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|css|js|ico)$ {
                expires max;
                log_not_found off;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        }
}
```

But when i visit `shop.local` i am getting redirecto to `shop.local/install/index.php` and nginx throws me an error 404. What's wrong with my config?

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
# FORCE WWW
server {
    server_name  site.com;
    rewrite ^(.*) http://www.domain.com$1 permanent;
}
# MAIN SERVER
server {
    server_name  www.domain.com;
    listen 80;
    root /var/www/www.domain.com/public;
    index index.php index.html;
    location /image/data {
        autoindex on;
    }
    location /admin {
        index index.php;
    }
    location / {
        try_files $uri @opencart;
    }
    location @opencart {
        rewrite ^/(.+)$ /index.php?_route_=$1 last;
    }
    location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }
    location = /robots.txt {
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }
    # Make sure files with the following extensions do not get loaded by nginx because nginx would display the source code, and these files can contain PASSWORDS!
    location ~* \.(engine|inc|info|install|make|module|profile|test|po|sh|.*sql|theme|tpl(\.php)?|xtmpl)$|^(\..*|Entries.*|Repository|Root|Tag|Template)$|\.php_ {
        deny all;
    }
    # Deny all attempts to access hidden files such as .htaccess, .htpasswd, .DS_Store (Mac).
    location ~ /\. {
        deny all;
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
    }
    location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|css|js|ico)$ {
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```